# Wifi hotspot automatically activating

Tags: wireless

**UBUNTU 18.04**

I have the wifi hotspot that gets automatically activated whenever my computer can't get connected to a wifi network.

For example, if I am connected to a network and I the connection is lost, even for a few seconds, my computer becomes a hotspot ! And I have to manually deactivate it ! If turn my wifi off then on, it goes on hotspot instead of just searching for a wifi network to connect to !

I don't know why this is happening but it started a while ago when I shared my internet connection to a friend (it was behaving fine and as expected before that) and it's quite annoying !

Comment: Hotspots create connection profiles... called Hotspot, or whatever you named the hotspot. Go to wi-fi settings and delete that connection profile, or, in `terminal`, use `nm-connection-editor` to find/delete that hotspot profile.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it helped me access its settings, I will comment how I did it and mark this as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @heynnema for the help !

How I solved my problem :

1. Open `terminal`
2. Enter `nm-connection-editor`
3. Find my connection, in my case it was named `Wi-Fi connection 2`
4. I selected it and here you can either delete it (the `-` button) or edit it (the `settings` button)
5. I chose to edit it and went to `general`->`Automatically connect to this network when it is available` and turned it off

And my problem is solved !

Comment: Thanks for the update. Good job!